# Having issue with controlling music with remoteControlReceived

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have MusicPlayer view controller which you can play some local mp3 files. I need to enable `remoteControlReceived` for my application to change music (play/pause , next) outside of app. My problem is the toggle buttons only work when app is in `MusicPlayerViewController`. For example if this vc dismisses or going to background those actions will not work any more ! . First I setup these notification in  `MusicPlayerViewController` :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Control Music

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playSong), name: NSNotification.Name("playSong"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(nextSong), name: NSNotification.Name("nextSong"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(previousSong), name: NSNotification.Name("previousSong"), object: nil)

}
```

Then in `AppDelegate` :

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


  //Play music when it's on BG
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

}



 override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        if event!.type == UIEventType.remoteControl{
            switch event!.subtype{
            case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPlay:
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("playSong"), object: nil)

            case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPause:
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("playSong"), object: nil)

            case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlNextTrack:
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("nextSong"), object: nil)

            case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPreviousTrack:
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("previousSong"), object: nil)

            default:
                print("There is an issue with the control")
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the problem which I cannot control AVPlayer from everywhere !

> PS: I also setup playing music in AppDelegate

Comment: Write code that you have didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: after Allocation of AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: @SharmaVishal Thanks ! it seems worked !

Comment: May i describe it as an answer for your up vote & answer acceptance?

Comment: @SharmaVishal  Yes sure ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply Category on AVAudioPlayer. 
So, you need to write below code after Allocation of AVAudioPlayer.

//  Allocation of your audio player & Then

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("AVAudioSession is Active")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Hope this will help you.